# Error starting iPython on Mac OSX: No module named jinja2

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pip, ipython

`iPython` was installed on a Mac OS X Mountain Lion using `pip`. When running `ipython notebook` in the Terminal, I get the error

```
...
File "/Users/god/.virtualenvs/datasci/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/html/notebookapp.py", line 38, in <module>
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
ImportError: No module named jinja2
```

**Question:** What is the problem here, and how should we resolve it?

Comment: Have you tried installing Jinja2? `pip install Jinja2`.

Comment: That works! Shouldn't `pip install ipython` install its dependencies too?

Comment: See http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/install/install.html; Jinja2 is optional.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Jinja 2 is listed as an *optional* dependency, see the [iPython quickstart](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/install/install.html).

You must install optional dependencies separately:

```
pip install Jinja2
```

You can install such dependencies as optional functionality groups for `ipython`. Using these let you install the dependencies needed for that functionality; each of these groups can be installed with `pip install ipython[groupname]`:

- `notebook`: for the [webbased notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook.html)
- `qtconsole`: for the [Qt console](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/qtconsole.html)
- `parallel` or `zmq`: for the ZMQ messaging support ([separate sharable kernel](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/overview.html#ipythonzmq))
- `doc`: tools required to generate the documentation
- `test`: dependencies to run the test suite
- `nbformat`: dependencies for producing the [notebook interchange format](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/interactive/nbconvert.html#notebook-json-file-format)
- `nbconvert`: dependencies for the [`nbconvert` tool](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/interactive/nbconvert.html) to convert the notebook format to other formats.

So to install all dependencies for `ipython notebook` use:

```
pip install ipython[notebook]
```

and `ipython` is installed *plus* the dependencies, or if you already have `ipython` installed it'll add on the missing packages.

Alternatively, install all optional dependencies with:

```
pip install ipython[all]
```

Comment: @Martijn--> Is it a good practice to install all the optional dependencies even when there might be plenty of them which I might never use?

Comment: @ShrikantKakani: That's up to you; it is easy enough to add the dependencies later on though. I doubt you'll run the iPython test suite, so you'd not need to install `nose`. I updated my answer to list all optional add-on groups separately.

Answer (score 1):

The notebook requires Jinja2.

To install just the required components for IPython notebook, use

```
$ pip install ipython[notebook]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just came across a very similar issue when using virtualenv and thought it would be useful to have the answer here. In my case, I had just installed ipython[notebook] but it still wasn't working:

```
(myvenv)$ ipython notebook
...
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
ImportError: No module named jinja2

(myvenv)$ pip install jinja2
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): jinja2 in ./luigi/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

When I exited the virtualenv I was in with `deactivate` and re-activated, everything was happy:

```
(myvenv)$ ipython notebook
[I ... NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Struggled with a similar issue which was created by running an upgrade.

Once the upgrade completed ipython notebook would throw the jinja error above.

If you experience this just uninstall jinja2 `pip uninstall ...`, and then `pip install Jinja2`. You may get a follow up error on another library. Rinse and repeat until you no longer get errors.

This solved my problem.